# In R, how can you plug a list into a function that accepts two arguments?

Tags: r

I have a function `f` that accepts two arguments, `a` and `b`. I have a list of values `x` that I'd like to plug in for `a`, while `b` is fixed. In Ruby, I'd use `map`, as in:

```
 x.map {|el| f(el,3) }
```

How do you write this in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**edited**: fixed argument order

Something like `lapply(x,f,b=3)` (or `sapply()`)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your function, you can sometimes use it directly, 
with a vector as first argument

```
f <- function(a,b) a+b
f(1:10,2)
```

or, if it does not work (if the function assumes that 
the first argument is a single number, as opposed to a vector),
you can vectorize it
(`Vectorize` just hides the call to `lapply`).

```
f <- Vectorize(f)
f(1:10,2)
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case `sapply` works fine (as @BenBolker answered), but `mapply` is also a good alternative, and actually the "best" solution when both `a` and `b` varies:

```
f <- function(a,b) a+b
x <- as.list(11:13) # you said you had a list...

# One argument (b) is fixed
sapply(x, f, 3) # 14 15 16
mapply(f, x, 3) # 14 15 16

# Both arguments vary
y <- 101:103
mapply(f, x, y) # 112 114 116
```